# The probability of drawing at least two diamonds among three cards drawn at random with replacement

Tags: probability

I am learning Random variables and Probability distribution. I got this question some what hard! Can somebody help me solve this please.

---

Three cards are drawn at random successively with replacement from a well shuffled pack of cards. Getting a card of "Diamond is termed as success". What is the sum of the probabilities of which random variable '$X$' will be $X \geq 2$.

---

Thank for your valuable time..

Comment: What is the random variable $X$? Is it the number of diamonds? And are you asking for the probability that the number of diamonds is $\ge 2$? That is a short calculation.

Comment: Try to choose more descriptive titles in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(X \geq 2) = P(X = 2) + P(X = 3)$,

where

$P(X = k) = \binom {3}{k} p^k(1-p)^{3-k}$,

with

$p = \dfrac{1}{4}$ (Diamond is 1 of 4 suits)

and $k = 2, 3$ for your question.

Comment: not understood brother..why does P(X=k) has come there...?

Comment: Thanks I got it,,
one last doubt...why is p=1/4. What made you assume that from the question...

Comment: This is because the probability of getting a diamond is $\frac{13}{52}=\frac{1}{4}$. Sorry @8pir about interjecting.

Comment: Thank you so much....Everybody...